# ¿Cómo enviar multiples datos de un subformulario a otro en Microsoft Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, microsoft

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando enviar todos los datos de un subformulario a otro formulario. No sé como se podría hacer porque lo único que he logrado es pasar los datos de la primera fila mediante este código

```
Private Sub Facturar_Click()
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Factura_Nueva", acFormAdd
 
Forms!Factura_Nueva![Fecha] = Me![Fecha]
Forms!Factura_Nueva![Cliente] = Me![Nombre_cliente]
Forms!Factura_Nueva![Cedula_Rif] = Me![Cedula_Rif]
Forms!Factura_Nueva![Numero_p] = Me![Numero_p]
Forms!Factura_Nueva![Fecha] = Me![Fecha]
End Sub
```

Pero me di cuenta de algo, no podia pasar todos los datos del subformulario así, solo los de la primera fila

Esta es la estructura de la forma que estoy usando. El subformulario de abajo se llama DETALLE_PRESUPUESTO Subformulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la forma a la cual debo alimentar, especificamente debo alimentar el subformulario que se llama Subformulario con los datos de DETALLE_PRESUPUESTO Subformulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías relacionarlos mediante SQL los datos y cargarlos en el subformulario. Piensa que los objetos formularios, como origen de datos, siempre van a tener una tabla o una consulta SQL. No hay otra opción (Salvo dejarlo sin datos). Te resultará mucho más fácil. Además, esta alimentación la puedes hacer en tiempo de ejecución desde VBA

Comment: Entendido, gracias